# Event for HTML 5 video streaming by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming

I create streaming video with node js and HTML 5 video.
And now i wanna set event for each buffing or maybe for stream packet.
How I can find useful event.
I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416602/html5-chuncked-video-streaming) that describe, how streaming happen and i need an event to fire for each chunk.

Answer (score 1):

There is no event for this on the media element, directly.  It's abstracted from view of your code.

However, if you're in control of the source, you can deploy a [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) which is effectively a proxy that you implement in JavaScript.  It's normally used for cache control, but you can use it to intercept and log when media requests are made.

Comment: what i can do if i wanna change header of every request or obtin to each response

Comment: @ghdarvishani Read up on Service Workers, and you'll see that you can do exactly that.